# MyISAM or InnoDB database for Prestashop?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, prestashop, myisam

I make my first eshop using Prestashop and I'm not sure if is better use MyISAM or InnoDB. In eshop could be max about 3 000 items.
I think that most important for that question is how much items will be in eshop, but if I didn't write some other important information, please ask me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This decision is dependent on read/write ratio. MYISAM uses table level level, so if a table is locked only one query can run on it hence MYISAM has serious performance issues. Also on prior version from 5.6 only MYISAM has support of FULLTEXT search. tables of MYISAM are really fast for SELECT queries and it takes less space on disk.

On the other hand, INNODB supports row-level locking hence concurrent select with insert is possible. It has support of doing ACID transactions hence each statement is atomic and durable in the event of crash.

So my decision is to use INNODB for application like eshop.

Answer (score 1):

I would use InnoDB because it supports transactions and that's likely necessary for an eshop.  For much more detailed information, check out the answers to this question:
[MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

Comment: Prestashop does not support transactions

Comment: As the accepted answer states, it's still better to use INNODB for the ACID support.